# What is this "Unknown Device" in Device Manager (Root\SQExtFramebufferUmode)

Tags: windows-10, drivers, device-manager, hardware-detection

My Microsoft Surface Book 3 15" laptop just updated to Windows 10, version 2004. After the update, there's a new "Unknown device" device listed in Device Manager. It didn't exist before today (August 15, 2020):

[image: Device Manager]
[image: Unknown device Properties]

According to the device properties, there is no driver installed for this device. Clicking "update driver" and searching my PC or Windows Update does not find a driver, or do anything to help identify the device.

When I go to the "Details" tab and scroll through the property dropdown, I can see that the device has a Hardware Id of "**Root\SQExtFramebufferUmode**" and a device instance path of "**ROOT\SQEXTFRAMEBUFFER\0000**". None of the other properties seem particularly helpful in identifying the device.

[image: Unknown device Hardware Ids]

Some other info that might be helpful:
Other than the Surface Book 3 built-in hardware, I have a Surface Dock 2 attached to my machine, and attached to that is a Corsair K68 USB keyboard, a Logitech M500s USB mouse, and a Dell U3419W monitor connected via USB-C to one of the monitor ports on the Surface Dock 2. The only other devices I have that are sometimes connected are a pair of Bose NC700 headphones, and an X-Box Wireless Controller Adapter, but neither of those devices were attached when this screenshot was taken.

Can anyone tell me what this device might be, and how I can obtain drivers for it?

Comment: That looks (Google Search) like it could be the Square Reader device. Is your Surface supposed to have this device?

Comment: @John, no I don't have a Square Reader.

Comment: right click on it and select uninstall, does it come back after a restart?

Comment: @Moab Huh, no it didn't. Uninstalled and rebooted. It's still gone. Weird. Problem... solved, I guess?

Comment: A driver install may have put it there, so it should stay gone until you reinstall that driver, what ever it was.

Answer (score 2):

This is a virtual Device from Squirrels LLC

Used by AirParrot

https://www.airsquirrels.com/airparrot/

Comment: That sounds plausible! I do have AirParrot 3 installed. How did you find this out?